# Masonry style Grid and jQuery UI sortable

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, grid

I have a grid, very simple, nothing special with no js involved.

I understand that the jQuery UI Sortable() is sortable in a linear position and this is the reason why it bugs out on a grid layout.

I have been googling for a while now with no success on how I get this to work without it bugging out.

I have a feeling that the only real way is not to use the grid.

I have set up a jsfiddle that can be seen here:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertg/ymzq6saf/6/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="dashwrapper">

<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="border-box margin-top-0 margin-bottom-0">

     <h2>Manage Signed Documents</h2>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">test test test</a></li>

  </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.dashwrapper{
  margin-top:20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2rem;
} 

.item{
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    break-inside: avoid;
    background:#f4f4f4;
  }
```

Here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

"use strict";

  const makeSortable = () => {
        $( ".dashwrapper" ).sortable({
            axis: "y",
            cursor: "grabbing"
        });
    }

 makeSortable();
    
});
```

Do I need to rethink the CSS and html or can this be fixed with a little JavaScript?